# SQL and number combination search

Tags: sql, search, combinations

I have table with 10 number fields (let's say `F1, F2... F10`).

Now I have 4 numbers (`N1, N2, N3, N4`).

I have to find if those 4 numbers appear anywhere in the above table. For example, if **F2=N4** and **F1=N2** and **Fx=N3** and **Fy=N1** (any order, any combination).

I was wondering is there quick way to do it via SQL or is it only way to write looooong combination of selects (I am not sure I will be able even finish that in this life time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faea7/3)**

Below is the sample Query

```
select * from Temp
where 'N1' in (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10)
  and 'N2' in (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10)
  and 'N3' in (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10)
  and 'N4' in (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10)
```

Comment: Thanks, this perfect. I was using something on the lines of 'select ("|" || F1 || "|" || F2 ||...) as combo where combo like "%|22|%" and combo like "%|26|%" and ...', but this is much better, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it (if your database supports it) would be to pivot the data so that each of the 10 columns has its own row.

So

```
ID F1 F2 F3 .. Fn
1  1  2  3     10
```

Becomes

```
ID F
1  1
1  2
1  3
..
1  10
```

You can now query for the existence of a given value of F against a single column, which simplifies things somewhat.

SQL Server supports this functionality [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)